# dyld[45524]: missing symbol called

Tags: nodejs, macos, nestjs

Estoy intentando ejecutar mi proyecto de nest con conexión a una base de datos db2 y ocurre un error

```
[Nest] 45524  - 13/07/2023, 15:27:47     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
dyld[45524]: missing symbol called
```

Me encuentro trabajando en una macbook pro m2 y tengo instaladas las siguientes versiones de node

```
nando@MacBook-Pro-de-Daniel prueba % nvm ls
->     v16.20.1
       v18.16.1
         system
default -> 18 (-> v18.16.1)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v18.16.1) (default)
stable -> 18.16 (-> v18.16.1) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.16.1)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.1
lts/hydrogen -> v18.16.1
```

he intentado ejecutarlo con rosetta 2 pero sigo teniendo el mismo error alguien que me pueda ayudar por favor?